# Generating fast normally distributed random numbers efficiently in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, random, normal-distribution

I've been looking for a fast and reliable way of generating normally distributed random numbers.

The most popular approach seems to be to use the Excel worksheet function Norm_Inv together with a random number, but this is quite slow because of the need to go back and forward between Excel and VBA.

I'm sharing my solution below, but if there is a better one, I'd love to know it.

Comment: would the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) be fast enough for you?  I don't use VB, but it's just something like `sqrt(-2 * log(Rnd)) * cos(2*pi*Rnd)`

Comment: I’ve tried that in the past and it’s OK, but this approach beats the pants off everything else for speed, because it consists of one random number and one lookup, once youve set up the array.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you're OK with only getting 1000 possible values from its range.  I'd prefer not to worry whether that is causing issues in my models, but I must admit I've not had to because I have always been able to efficiently generate full-precision (i.e. 53 bits rather than ~10) variates.  another approach might be to write some C# code and call that from VBA?

Comment: you could increase it to 10000 if you like, but how often would you need that resolution?

Comment: different applications have different constraints; e.g. even with 10000 elements you'd only have to generate [100 variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) before having a ~50% chance of seeing a duplicate (and only ~32 with 1000 array elements).  presumably this doesn't matter to you, but this could break some monte-carlo algorithms

Answer (score 0):

This solution is extremely fast and as accurate as you need it to be. Initially, you divide the interval 0-1 into a large number of slices and call NORM_INV to get the normal distribution value at each point, storing the values in an array. After that, you don't need to call NORM_INV any more, and can just look up the array value for any random number.

1000 slices seems to be enough to give a 99%+ correlation with using NORM_INV directly.

```
Function NormalRandLookup(Optional Mean As Single = 0, Optional StdDev As Single = 1) As Single
  Static R() As Single, n As Long 
  If n = 0 Then 'set up the lookup table initially
    Dim i As Long
    n = 1000 'vary this to reduce or increase accuracy 
    ReDim R(0 To n)
    R(0) = -3.3: R(n) = 3.3 'the extreme values returned by NORM_INV for 0 and 1
    For i = 1 To n - 1 
      R(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(i / n, 0, 1)
    Next i
  End If
  NormalRandLookup = Mean + StdDev * R(Rnd * n)
End Function
```